# Writing a function with a callback

Tags: javascript

Lets imagine that I have some code:

```
var someString = "";
function do1(){
    doA();
    doB();
}

function doA(){
    // some process that takes time and gets me a value
    someString = // the value I got in prior line

function doB(){
    //do something with someString;
}
```

What is the correct way to make sure somestring is defined by doB tries to use it?  I think this is a situation that calls for a callback, but I'm not sure how to set it up?

Comment: What exactly is “some process that takes time”? Is it asynchronous, i.e. does the function return before it completes?

Comment: I guess I'm a little confused.  I know that I would need a solution in cases where the code is asynchronous (such as something that uses ajax), but is there ever a case where doB could execute before doA merely because doA is very slow (i.e. some huge loop), or does code always run line by line unless a line is asynchronous?

Comment: Well yeah. If it is asynchronous it will not run line by line. If you are doing an ajax call inside doA(), it most likely is asynchronous (don't set async to false). If you have a gigantic loop in doA() that will set someString to something this will still run before doB(). But in case of large loops you might want to have a look into webworkers which will allow you to do multi threading.

Comment: "is there ever a case where doB could execute before doA merely because doA is very slow (i.e. some huge loop)" - no.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, I have solved this problem like following code by callback parameter. However,  I don't know this is correct answer. In my case, it's done well.

```
var someString = "";
function do1(){ 
    doA(doB);
}

function doA(callback){
    // some process that takes time and gets me a value
    someString = // the value I got in prior line
    callback();
}

function doB(){
    //do something with someString;
}
```

Comment: `doA(function(){doB()});` could be reduced to `doA(doB);`

Comment: Oh thanks!! :) I didn't know that. I'm going to fix it.

Comment: I believe I could easily take this and use it.  But I don't understand it.  Would you mind telling me a little bit more about the logic of this code?

Comment: If you want to execute two different functions in consecutive order, you should wait first function is finished. For instance, if you want to execute doB after doA, you should wait "doA" function is finished. For this, we need to pass the parameter about doB function to doA. In doA, as you received the information about doB by the parameter, you just call the parameter callback function which means doB in end of doA. 

I'm sorry that my english is very poor...

Answer (score 0):

I usually write these such that the function can be called with, or without, the callback function.  You can do this by calling the `callback` function only if `typeof callback === 'function'`. This allows the function which includes the possibility of a callback to be a bit more general purpose.  The call to the `callback()`, obviously, needs to be from within the callback of whatever asynchronous operation you are performing. In the example below, `setTimeout` is used as the asynchronous action.

```js
var someString = "";
 
function do1() {
    doA(doB); //Call doA with doB as a callback.
}
 
function doA(callback) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        //setTimeout is an example of some asynchronous process that takes time
        //Change someString to a value which we "received" in this asynchronous call.
        someString = 'Timeout expired';
        //Do other processing that is normal for doA here.

        //Call the callback function, if one was passed to this function
        if (typeof callback === 'function') {
            callback();
        }
    }, 2000);
}
 
function doB() {
    //do something with someString;
    console.log(someString);
}

do1();
```

You can, of course, do this without using a global variable:

```js
function do1() {
    doA(doB); //Call doA with doB as a callback.
}
 
function doA(callback) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        //setTimeout is an example of some asynchronous process that takes time
        //Simulate a result
        var result = 'Timeout expired'; 

        //Do other processing that is normal for doA here.

        //Call the callback function, if one was passed to this function
        if (typeof callback === 'function') {
            callback(result);
        }
    }, 2000);
}
 
function doB(result) {
    console.log(result);
}

do1();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function someFunctionA(callback){
  var someString = "modify me";
  callback(someString);
}

function someFunctionB(someString){
  // do something
}

function main() {
   someFunctionA(somefunctionB);
 }
```